# Storing Objects into a Java file won't work

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

The instruction says: I need to create an JavaFX application where when a button labelled Write is pressed, it stores an array of five int values 1,2,3,4, and 5, a Date object for current time, and a double value 5.5. into a file named Exercise17_05.dat. Then write a method in the program that opens Exercise17_05.dat, reads the data and displays to the command window. In addition have a button label Read, which when pressed, the program will read and displays the content of Exercise17_05.dat ( created by the write ). Use a TextArea to display the results and have the text color blue and the background grey

I feel like I am getting close but I keep getting this error "The target type of this expression must be a functional 
 interface". The Javafx box won't even open up because of the error so I can't really check my progress. Where did I go wrong?

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class module3 extends Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

        // Text area
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey; -fx-text-fill: blue; -fx-control-inner-background: grey");
        textArea.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));


        Button write = new Button("Write");
        write.setOnAction(e -> {
            // Create an output stream for file
            try(ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Exercise17_05.dat", true))) {
                int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
                // Write to file
                // 1. Write double
                output.writeDouble(5.5);
                // 2. Write int array object
                output.writeObject(numbers);
                // 3. Write date object
                output.writeObject(new java.util.Date());
                // 4. Write utf string
                output.writeUTF("Exercise17_05.dat");

            } catch(IOException exception) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });



        Button read = new Button("Read");
        read.setOnAction(e -> {

            //Create an input stream for file
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Exercise17_05.dat"));

            // Read from file
               // 1. Read double
             double doubleValue = input.readDouble();
             textArea.appendText("Double value: " + doubleValue);
             // 2. Read int array object
             int[] newNumbers = (int[]) (input.readObject());
             textArea.appendText("Integers: " + Arrays.toString(newNumbers));
             // 3. Read date object
             Date date = (java.util.Date) (input.readObject());
             textArea.appendText("DateTime: " + date);
             // 4. Read utf string
             String fileName = input.readUTF();      


              } catch(IOException exception) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }


        HBox hButtons = new HBox(read, write);
        VBox vProgram = new VBox(hButtons, textArea);



    }   
}
```

Comment: Does the code for the "Read" action have a `try` to go with that `catch`?

Comment: And the issue occurs where? And please take more care with manipulating your code, before you post it: it removed that `try` part in `read.setOnAction(e -> {`.

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Exercise17_05.dat"));
```

to

```
try(ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Exercise17_05.dat"));){
```

(see Toms comment, but I think it was not a problem with code manipulation before posting, I think this actually the original code)

after doing that you will notice, that some closing brackets are missing (insert `});` after catch block)

You will need to catch `ClassNotFoundException` and add some imports as well.

Comment: catch `ClassNotFoundException`? Are you serious??